# Nginx + React app with router+ Chrome = subfolders do not work

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kibana, service-worker

I have a react app running under nginx. App runs just fine and there are no problems.

Now, I have kibana and portainer running on the same server and I configured nginx to run them as a subfolder. The server have a security certificate and I can't really create new sub-domains. So I had to go with the subfolders.

```
server {
listen       80;
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  api.nec.private.systems;

ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/api.nec.private.systems.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/api.nec.private.systems.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
    # Set path
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

# Do not cache sw.js, required for offline-first updates.
location /sw.js {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    expires off;
    access_log off;
}


location /control/ {
    proxy_pass http://portainer:9000/;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    expires off;
    access_log off;
}
    location /kibana/ {
    proxy_pass http://kibana:5601/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    expires off;
    access_log off;
}
}
```

As you can see the first two locations describe the react app and the last two are all about kibana and poratiner.

Now, here is the problem:

1. I would open google chrome and go to api.nec.private.systems/control - it would pull up portainer without any problems.
2. I would open api.nec.private.systems/kibana and would get kibana as expected.
3. I would open api.nec.private.systems/ and the react app with the react router would open.
4. Now, having done step #3 I would open api.nec.private.systems/kibana and it won't open kibana anymore, rather it would try to feed /kibana in my router. It WON'T open kibana at all. No matter how much I would try.
5. Step number X - clear cache of google chrome and try again - kibana and poirtainer works just fine. Until I'll open the react app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out my own problem here. It's all because of the service worker that comes with create-react-app. Basically, service worker trying to redirect all requests from the app to the local storage cache.

Killed the service worked and it started working fine.